# What is the easiest way to manage shopping cart without user log in in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello I am still a beginner to Asp.net and I want to know what is the easiesy way to manage shopping cart without user login?

I researched and find out that you can use Cookies,Session and Windowstorage but which one is easiest and use less time?

I try reading and still confused

Comment: Define "Easy". Questions based on qualitative judgement tend to get closed as "opinion-based".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.